# Openlayers STContains, intersecting lines

Tags: c#, openlayers, spatial, clipping

I have an app running OpenLayers and have come across an interesting problem.

I create a polygon, called Project.
Then I have sub-projects that are inside that polygon.

The first time you create a sub-project, I clip the sub-project so that it is inside the Project.

`SpatialManager.ClipShape(subShape, projectShape);`

When you go to edit a project, I want to make sure that you keep the sub-project inside the Project.

`if(projectShape.STContains(subShape).isFalse)`

The problem comes with the clipping/contains.  When clipping, the project and sub-project share the same boundary lines.

`STContains` wont be true because they share lines.

Is there anyway to check if a polygon contains a percentage of another shape, or contains with sharing lines?

Thanks.

[image: clipping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [STIntersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933899.aspx), which will return true if either polygon has any point in common with the other, including on an edge. You might also find [STTouches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933953.aspx) useful, which will return true if two polygons touch, even at a single point, but do not have any interior points inside the other. `STContains` isn't working for you because the polygons share a common boundary, or to quote from the DE-9IM explained below:

> Geometry b lies in the interior of a. Another definition: "a 'contains' b iff no points of b lie in the exterior of a, and at least one point of the interior of b lies in the interior of a

There is something with the slightly scary name of [Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM), which is abbreviated to DE-9IM for obvious reasons, which explains the underlying theory of spatial predicates.